# If I'm farming the Warrior using the moonshot, can I switch to the new Tiny Tina DLC and still farm?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've been farming the Warrior on UVHM (finally got there last night), but I also want to play the new DLC. If I jump to Dragon Keep (or whatever the station is for the new DLC), will I still be able to continue farming the Warrior with moonshots?

My assumption is that I'll have to kill everything on the way there (since I can't just teleport into the Vault of the Hunter) but not have to kill the Warrior again. Is that correct?

Comment: How exactly are you farming with moonshots? I'm extremely confused, I thought you had to save and quit, then kill the Warrior again.  I don't understand how you farm a moonshot when you need to do the quest again to activate it (kill Handsome Jack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally just tried doing it myself, and it indeed still works. So you can switch to any DLC, come back, and still moonshot farm the Warrior.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave the Vault of the Warrior map you'll have to fight your way back, since your "resume" location will no longer be the Vault and you can only fast travel back to the start of Hero's Pass.

Comment: But I can still continue to farm the Warrior after making it back to the Vault? :)

Comment: Yes. All bosses respawn. The Warrior will be there when you get back.

Comment: But right now, the Warrior is dead whenever I load into the Vault (since I'm at the "Call moonshot" objective). Will he still respawn when I go back? I would assume he'd be dead (as he is now).

Comment: @WaynnLue oh, I didn't even know that was possible. But yeah, the main quest objectives should stay in exactly their current state